# I cannot use JQuery in login page?

Tags: jquery, authentication, asp.net

I'm with a problem than right now i'm not understanding..

I'm using JQuery to render a icon "loading ajax" always than a request page is done.

All my pages derives from master page, but login page doens't.

What happens is that page (login) i cannot use jquery

In login page im including to jquery library and using the following code to test

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                console.log('blbalbl');
               });   
        </script>
```

but $ is not recognized..

If i remove

```
$(function(){
```

and leave

```
console.log('blabla');
```

blablbal will appear in console..

Anybody knows what is happening?

regards

---

Guys i already included the library jQuery but still not work

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js") %>'></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { 
    console.log('blbalbl'); 
  }); 
</script>
```

In my master page the script works, but in the login doesn't

I already try no conflict with `.$noConflict` but the problem is than $ is unrecognized.

Answer (score 2):

You are not loading the jQuery library.

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works

Look for a line like this in your master page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

so just add one of these to your page with the problem and then it will work.

Comment: it is better to request specific jquery version `1.3.2`, as it will have expiry date set long into the future and will be cached.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess. If you are using any other library then you have to use **[jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)**

```
$.noConflict();
  jQuery(function() {
      console.log('blbalbl');
  });
```

Also check that your reference for the jQuery file is the right one. You can use firebug to find out that.

```
<script src="jQuery.js" type="text/javascript></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function {
    //do your thang
});
```

If that works, you must have some kind of conflict. If not, you need to make sure you are loading jQuery correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You mention a Master page, is this an Asp.net site?  Are you using Forms Authentication?  If so you will need to add a section to your web.config to give all users access to your javascript files.

Comment: Not often.  Usually .js files are served by IIs and not processed by .net